# Java FX 8 Tablecell data to Listview selected data

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a Java FX TableView with a column. This column is pre-populated with values from a database. When I click a cell on the table a listview is shown, I can update the table cell and the DB by selecting the values from the list.

Before the listview shows up, I  set the selected value of the list to match the existing table cell's value by the following

```
listView.getSelectionModel().select(this.getItem());
```

when the list view opens the selected item corresponds to the cell value of the table.

I have a onchangelistener attached to the listview's selectedItemProperty.

From this list view if I choose a new value, When the selection changes the DB gets updated and the table cell gets updated with the new value.

If there is a problem with the database update, the listview's selected ItemProperty still retains the newly selected value.

I have tried resetting it using

```
listView.getSelectionModel().select(this.getItem());
```

but this doesn't reset the selectedItemProperty value.

Hence if you click the same cell once again, the list is having the previously selected value highlighted (i.e the value which was not updated due to a DB failure) the table cell and the selected value in the listview are different.

How do I overcome this ?

Comment: You can use listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection() first of use select .